# Kubernetes service selector used to select another service and not deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

I just want to know, is it possible to refer to a service rather than a deployment (using service labels instead of deployment matchLabels) in a Kubernetes service definition?
What I mean to say is suppose I have a service A defined which exposes a deployment A-D and now I want to define another service B but this time instead of its selector referring to a deployment A-D I want it to point to the previous service defined i.e. service A? Is this even possible in Kubernetes? For eg see the scenario below

```
**Deployment A-D**
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

**ServiceA**
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx-1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my-nginx

**ServiceB**
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-wrapper-service
  labels:
    run: my-nginx-2
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my-nginx-1  //service label instead of deployment
```

UPDATE:

```
headless service
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: access-service
      annotations:
        getambassador.io/config: |
          ---
          apiVersion: ambassador/v1
          kind: Mapping
          name: productreadservice-mapping
          prefix: /Apps/ProductReadService/.*
          prefix_regex: true
          rewrite: ""
          service: access-service:80
    spec:
      clusterIP: None
      ports:
      - name: http
        port: 80
        targetPort: 8082

endpoint object
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: access-service
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: ip of the service i wish to access
  ports:
  - port: 8082
    protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! Not through selectors though.

Ones you have the service pointing to the pods A-D, you have an IP address. You can create an `Endpoints` object  with that IP address. Then, you can create a `headless service` without selectors with the same name as the `Endpoints` object.

Example:

Say your service IP address (The one pointing to the Depoyments A-D) is 10.0.0.10. Create the `Endpoints` object:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-headless-service
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.0.0.10
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

Now, create the headless service with the same name as the `Endpoints`object. Note that it has no label selectors, so it is not selecting any backend. When this happens, the request is send to the DNS, and there it will search for  either en `ExternalName` type service with the same name or an `Endpoints` object with the same name.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-headless-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

The resolution happens at DNS, not at iptables.

Comment: does this works with ambassador because it looks like my headless service isnt being discovered by ambassador

Comment: Yeah, it should work for all use cases. You mean from the ambassador you can't reach the service? How are you making the request?

Comment: what i mean is as per your advice i created a headless service without any selector and created mapping for it with ambassador annotations but when i try to reach it it gives  service unavailable error 503

Comment: Oh, I thought you had a sidecar container. Not sure how is `Ambassador` making the request. It also throws an error when you set the FQDN of the service (svc-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local)?

Comment: From ambassador i meant the kubernetes native api gateway https://www.getambassador.io/

Comment: Yes, I got you. This pattern should work for all use cases, as this is not a workaround. It is meant to target a service from another service. Where are you exactly setting the headless service name? What is a mapping with ambassador annotations?

Comment: just came across this in kubernetes docs"Endpoint IP addresses cannot be the cluster IPs of other Kubernetes Services, because kube-proxy doesn’t support virtual IPs as a destination."  .does this means the approach we are taking wont work?

Comment: I see. I don't know if with that annotation it is going to work as you want. But you can point with an endpoints object to another service IP for sure. Just make a simple test to see it working. Create a simple deployment and a `ClusterIP` service pointing to it. Then do all the endpoints and headless service, and you will see that it works.

Comment: this does not work if you want to ultimately connect to something that are not pods,  because service cannot map to other services. For example you cannot ask a `LoadBalancer` Service to map to a `ExternalNames` Service

Comment: @Ghilteras you map a headless service to an ExternalName. But a LoadBalancer points directly to ClusterIp. That's why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible. The selector needs to select pod labels only.